# NativeScript: ChildActivationStart Event getting triggered causing my page to redirect

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Issue - I am on login page and click on Login button which should take me to Staff List page. However i am redirected back to login. When debugged, i saw that its happening because of ChildActivationStart.

So navigation which should work as Login -> Staff-list
is working as Login -> Staff-list -> Login (back due to additional Child Route Processing) navigationTrigger is shown as "hashchange" for additional route ""

I upgraded my mobile app in NativeScript from Angular 4.4 to Angular 6.1. Post doing that, i found that there is some routing issue that has started occurring. On debugging it, i found that the issue is because of the new event ChildActivationStart that has been added while routing.

Code to reproduce issue can be found at https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lrIrYT&v=5

Here is my scenario

app.routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "",redirectTo: "authentication", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "authentication", component: AuthenticationComponent },
  { path: "staff-list/:id", component: StaffListComponent },
];
```

In my AuthenticationComponent, I do navigate to staff-list when i click on login button

```
export class AuthenticationComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
        private _router: Router
    ) {}
    //on login tap btn
    loginTap(args: EventData) {
....
                this._router.navigate(['/staff-list']);

    }
}
```

I have enabled the tracing for routes and here is the log that i found is as follows.

```
JS: Router Event: ActivationEnd
JS: ActivationEnd(path: 'staff-list/:id')
JS: ActivationEnd(path: 'staff-list/:id')
JS: Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
JS: ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
JS: ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
JS: Router Event: NavigationEnd
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/staff-list/10', urlAfterRedirects: '/staff-list/10')
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/staff-list/10', urlAfterRedirects: '/staff-list/10')
JS: Router Event: Scroll
JS: Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
JS: Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
JS: Router Event: NavigationStart
JS: NavigationStart(id: 3, url: '/authentication')
JS: NavigationStart(id: 3, url: '/authentication')
JS: Router Event: RoutesRecognized
JS: RoutesRecognized(id: 3, url: '/authentication', urlAfterRedirects: '/authentication', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'authentication', path:'authentication') } )
JS: RoutesRecognized(id: 3, url: '/authentication', urlAfterRedirects: '/authentication', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'authentication', path:'authentication') } )
JS: Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
JS: GuardsCheckStart(id: 3, url: '/authentication', urlAfterRedirects: '/authentication', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'authentication', path:'authentication') } )
JS: GuardsCheckStart(id: 3, url: '/authentication', urlAfterRedirects: '/authentication', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'authentication', path:'authentication') } )
JS: Router Event: ChildActivationStart
```

Issue is occurring since ChildActivationStart with a '' route which takes it back to AuthenticationComponent.

On checking why this behavior has occurred after upgrading to Angular 6.x, i found [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866278/why-does-childactivationstart-event-trigger-eventhough-we-dont-have-a-child-rou) reported as well but couldn't see any solution. Why does child routing events occur when we have not explicitly routed to any child links? Can this issue come because of components being in different modules? Currently structure that i have is

```
AppModule
    - AuthenticationModule
    - StaffModule
```

However all routing is handled via AppModule itself through app.routes.ts. This issue does not come when i downgrade Angular to 4.x version again. Can that be a probable reason for ChildRoutes getting activated?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here- can you please clarify...

Comment: @NickIliev I have modified content. Please let me know if something is not clear

Comment: It seems that in your routing table you have a path `"staff-list/:id` (which requires :id) but then you are not passing any ID when navigating to the staff page

Comment: @NickIliev i am adding it. It gets routed to correct component as well while debugging. If you see logs, here is the navigation 
JS: NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/staff-list/10', urlAfterRedirects: '/staff-list/10') .... This code works when i had Angular 4.x along with Nativescript 3.x.... However without any code change, when i upgraded, its not routing correctly

Comment: Are you having some guards logic on the staff page? Here is a Playground that uses your code and everything works as expected https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lrIrYT

Comment: no guards are used...

Comment: Check the playground demo and compare the code with your own to see what is causing the different behaviour - the playground is working as expected

Comment: I verified the code and modified the same to match my scenario. When i am enablingTrace in playground, its not showing childActivationPath. Even other apps which i have created directly on Angular 6, seems to be working fine. However i am not getting from where this activation path is getting added when i upgrade my current app.

Comment: @NickIliev Trigger for this addition was shown as "hashchange". Any reason why this page would have "hashchange" event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178599/discussion-between-rajan-phatak-and-nick-iliev).

Comment: @NickIliev I could reproduce scenario. It has something to do with Modal dialog changes in Nativescript 4. Please check code at https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=lrIrYT&v=5 which reproduces scenario that i am facing

Comment: @NickIliev This is breaking change for application migrating from NativeScript 3.x to NativeScript 4.x since new modal navigation is added. NativeScript 3.x applications does not make use of navigation

Comment: @NickIliev I earlier thought that this was issue was specific to nativescript angular version as mentioned in https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/issue-with-directly-opening-a-modal-dialog-box/7796 ... However when i work with code on playground, i still see same issue with Angular 7.1 and Nativescript 5.2 ... Can someone please look at the issue?

Comment: @NickIliev Steps to reproduce 1. Go to Home Screen 2. Click on Login Tap 3. Popup appears. Click on Select button. 4. You should be routed to Staff page. (ideally). 5. If you are routed correctly, please click back and repeat steps from 1 to 4. 6, Auto redirection happens to login page after clicking select button